# ampscript lookup to pull in all rows of data

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, lookup

I am trying to use the LookUpRows function to display specific attributes associated with the 2 members in my Data Extension.

The attributes are `MEMBER_NAME`, `MEMBER_NUMBER`, `CUSTOMER_TYPE` & `PLAN_TYPE`

I'm written some AMPscript that doesn't throw me an error. However I can't display the attributes in my email so something must be wrong in my code.

Any guidance is appreciated!

**Lookup Data Extension**

| MEMBER_NAME | MEMBER_NUMBER | EMAIL | CUSTOMER_TYPE | PLAN_TYPE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 123 | john@example.com | High | Type 1 |
| Doe | 456 | Doe@example.com | Low | Type 2 |

**AMPSCRIPT**

```
set @lookupPlan = LookUpRows("My_DE","MEMBER_NAME",1)

set @countMember1 = rowcount(@lookupPlan)

IF @countMember1 > 0 THEN

    set @member1name = Field(Row(@LookupPlan,1),"MEMBER_NAME")
    set @member1number = Field(Row(@LookupPlan,1),"MEMBER_NUMBER")
    set @member1customer = Field(Row(@LookupPlan,1),"CUSTOMER_TYPE")
    set @member1plan = Field(Row(@LookupPlan,1),"PLAN_TYPE")

ENDIF

]%%
```

**HTML**

```
%%=v(@member1name)=%%
%%=v(@member1number)=%%
%%=v(@member1customer)=%%
%%=v(@member1plan)=%%
```

Comment: with this example your lookup rows would return 0 rows

Comment: Silly question, but why so if I'm using the greater than operator?

Comment: lookuprows doesn't have a greater than operand https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/lookuprows.html you ampscript as written would only return a row where member_name = 1

Comment: @EazyE I understand, however this is further confusing me. Most examples I see include `> 0 then`. For example - https://sprignaturemoves.com/ampscript-lookup-examples/

Comment: then > is evaluating the rowcount returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lookuprows in currently searching for records where member_name = 1, I’m sure that’s not what you want it to do. I assume you want to be able to search by the plan type. If yes, try something like this:

```
set @lookupPlan = LookUpRows("My_DE","PLAN_TYPE","Type 1")
```

Comment: Thanks this does work. However, I would like to look for all records, without having to search by plan type, name, or customer type

Comment: Then you’d need to add a new column to your DE and have the name value for all records, eg. column called `lookup` and value `1` for all records and then in your script do `set @lookupPlan = LookUpRows("My_DE","lookup","1")`